Framing / Insulate a basement with the lowest profile
My basement has a fireplace, which is pretty low profile against the foundation (~3.5"). My understanding is that I should insulate with rigid foam right against the foundation, and then frame on top of that. With 2" insulation, the wall would be sticking out 2+" further than the fireplace, which is super weird. I have two main questions:

Is 1" (r5) insulation on the foundation suitable for a vapor barrier etc? I am in zone 4-C, my basement seems to have no moisture, and I think that the walls were painted with a leak proof paint ~35 years ago. (I recently demoed the walls because they were OSB, and the faced insulation in there had no moisture damage).

Can I frame with sideways 2x4s, in order to have a lower profile? At least on that wall, that would save me a lot of room to have my drywall be flush with the fireplace. If I did that, how do you frame the baseplate? A 2x2?


In general, lower profile on all walls is best since it gives more space in the smallish rooms, but otherwise I at the very least need a smaller profile on the fireplace wall.

Please rephrase the question. Does this fireplace already exist and you are planning to insulate the wall around it?

Against a foundation wall you can have 2x4s sideways.  They are mainly just something for nails/screws to go into/spacers.

@DelphicOracle yes, the fireplace already exists and I'm planning to insulate the wall around it, which is mostly below grade. The fireplace is brick, and about 3.5" proud of the wall.
